# Largest possible number of multiplicity in a regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

Is there a conjecture that states the biggest possible number diagonals of a regular polygon intersecting at one single point in the regular polygon outside of the intersection point of all the diameters?

Comment: Huh?  Can't you simply solve directly for this?

Comment: Can you state the question a different way? I cannot tell what you are asking.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known — see [this amazing paper](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Emrubinst/publications/ngon.pdf) by Poonen and Rubinstein!

The maximum number of diagonals incident to a non-center point in the interior of a regular $n$-gon (for $n > 4$) is

$$\begin{cases}
2 &: n~\text{is odd} \\
3 &: n~\text{is even and not divisible by}~6 \\
5 &: n~\text{is divisible by}~6~\text{and not divisible by 30} \\
7 &: n~\text{is divisible by}~30
\end{cases}$$